# How to organize music?

Tags: tags, music-management

You might also have the problem that the music on your computer is a mess. Programs like WMP or iTunes are not capable to identify the music and sort it into categories.

Is there a solution (a program, a mod or a add-on) which scans my computer for music, erases duplicates, adjusts volume, categorizes in genres & quality, adds missing titles and artist names?

I don’t want to spend a year doing it on my own.

Comment: A don't think you'll find any one tool that does everything you want & there'll always be a degree of intervention required.

Comment: +1 good question, media and file management solutions don't seem growing in capability as fast as storage capacity

Comment: While musicbrainz is great and tagging mp3 is nice, those are just a small part of the question. @Shail, did you ever manage to find something?

Answer (score 9):

I use [MusicBrainz' Picard Tagger](http://musicbrainz.org/) which allows you to add tags and move files to sorted folders and rename files. It not only uses your existing filenames and tags but also the audio footprint of any music. The database is quite large and collaborative.

> *MusicBrainz is a community music
>   metadatabase that attempts to create a
>   comprehensive music information site.
>   You can use the MusicBrainz data
>   either by browsing this web site, or
>   you can access the data from a client
>   program — for example, a CD player
>   program can use MusicBrainz to
>   identify CDs and provide information
>   about the CD, about the artist or
>   about related information. You can
>   also use the MusicBrainz Tagger to
>   automatically identify and clean up
>   the metadata tags in your digital
>   music collections.*

It will not scan your entire hard drive and do the entire work for you but it still removes a lot of pain when sorting music.

Comment: i would point out though, it has an unfortunate tendancy to favor compilations in my experience. Nothing beats it for totally unknown songs tho

Comment: Nowadays anyway, the Metadata / Preferred-release-types option screen has sliders  which seem to allow you to adjust its tendencies.

Answer (score 3):

There's no software available which can do everything you want unattended, but there are a lot of tools and utilities which can make life easier for what you want.

That said, I've been very happy with [Mp3 Tag Tools](http://massid3lib.sourceforge.net/), an open source mp3 toolset with the following features:

> - ID3v1.1 & ID3v2.x support
> - Tag mp3s even while playing them
> - Mass ID3 tagging
> - Custom Filename Format specification like "() -  -  -
>     " using shortcuts "(*1) - *2 -
>     *3 - *0" or selecting checkboxes
> - Write ID3 tags from Filenames using Custom Filename Format
> - Rename Filenames From ID3 tags using Custom Filename or Directory Format
> - Remove All ID3v1.1 or ID3v2.x tags
> - Remove All Non-ID3 tags
> - Create ID3 tags using Directory Formats
> - Create Directories and organize mp3s from ID3 tag info
> - Selectively Copy or Synchronize ID3v1.1 & ID3v2.x tags
> - Sort and export tag data as Tab delimited text files for import to
>     spreadsheet programs
> - Lyrics and Picture tagging
> - Cleaning Filenames of unwanted charachters such as %20 and
>     underscores "_", remove excess
>     whitespace, Correcting their case to
>     capitalize the first letter of each
>     word or after symbols or prefix words
> - Accurately read all MPEG info and append bitrate and mode to filenames
> - Recursion - All these tag operations can be carried out  by individually
>     selecting one or more files from a mp3
>     tag list, created by searching a
>     specified directory with or without
>     recursion.
> - Use MTT as a hard drive mp3 search tool and virtual playlist

Answer (score 2):

For volume adjustment, [MP3Gain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3Gain) and [AACgain](http://www.rarewares.org/aac-encoders.php) are great - they adjust metatags so there's no loss in quality. In addition to that I use [Mp3tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mp3tag) for mass manual adjustment of tags, and [MusicBrainz Picard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MusicBrainz_Picard) for songs I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Only a partial solution, but [Media Monkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com) will add all files under a specified root to your library. From there you can select a number of files and then:

> Tools > Auto Tag From Web...

which will retrieve a lot of information for you.

From [this page](http://www.mediamonkey.com/information/free/) on their site:

> **Identify Tracks**
>
> Automatically identify tracks that are missing information, whose tags are not synchronized, or that are duplicated elsewhere.
>
> Fix Tags with Automatic Lookup and Tagging of album art and other track information from Amazon.
>
> Lookup CD information on Freedb or via CD-TEXT, and find missing track details through music-related sites such as Allmusic.
>
> If you have a large music collection, MediaMonkey will help you update your tags quickly and accurately.

If you have tracks tagged but with incorrect filenames then it can generate names based on tags too.

It has a number of search and filter options so you can find "Files to Edit" with missing Title, Artist, Album, Genre, Year etc.

It will also do the the volume levelling and as above you can find the "Unleveled" tracks in your library.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use [Helium Music Manager](http://www.helium-music-manager.com/) long ago, when it was called Helium2.  It is very complicated and has *a lot* of features, and I cannot be bothered with stuff like that anymore.

[image]

Comment: what you mean? that hellium does everything he asked but you use some out of the box solution? or you just don't care with organizing music anymore?

Comment: @Cawas: I don't bother using such software anymore, as any music files that I rip, buy, download or copy usually is tagged sufficiently already.  If it is not, I just use the automatic tools in Windows Music Player.

Comment: that's exactly what I'd like to be able to do myself... but my old and bloated music collection along with some new file I get are just not there yet! :( but it's nice to hear some people can achieve music nirvana without needing to stick to kurt cobain (nonsense)! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with the command-line, you might consider giving [beets](http://beets.radbox.org/) (an open-source project I'm working on) a try. Like Picard, it automatically corrects tags based on the [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/) database, but beets has more focus on keeping your music organized after the initial import. (It has a very flexible directory structure feature, for example.) Being a command-line MusicBrainz client, beets might be best for more technically-inclined music nerds.

Answer (score 0):

Along with [Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/) for filling in blanks, I generally use Softpointer's [Tag&Rename](http://www.softpointer.com/tr.htm) to do the actual renaming.

It allows creation of folders on the fly as part of the rename, using variables to define the target folders.

So using something like `G:\Mp3s\%1\%3(%4)\%1_%6_%2` as the file name mask results in files named like `G:\Mp3s\<Artist>\<Album>(<Year>)\<Artist>_<Track #>_<Title>.mp3`.

Other bits I like:

- It can get full album info and art from a couple DB's (freeCDDB and Amazon mainly), without the full album.
- Supports many/most file types.
- File name cleanup (capitalization, etc.).
- Really nice multi-file manual tag editing as well as batch edits.