# Advanced ID3 tags handling and audio files ordering

Tags: windows, mp3, id3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to organize music?](https://superuser.com/questions/87792/how-to-organize-music)

Some of my files do not have complete ID3 tags and some have typos or small differences in writing – so finally, my portable player sees “Mr. President” as different artist from “Mr President” and so on.

I would need some tool which could search similar tags and then allow me to correct the typos or for example override `artist` in all selected files by manually entered text.

The same with empty `tag` items – sometimes, the `track name`, `album` etc. is OK, but the `artist` is missing etc.

I'd like to do this without touching the audio quality, of course (but this should be no problem, I think).

I already tried tools like:

- Winamp
- Songbird
- other players
- Tagscanner – the most advanced free tool I tried. However, it is not able to to solve the problem with similar tags.

Do you know such tool? Preferably free and for Windows, if possible. However, if you know some commercial app able to do this, please let me know.

Comment: and/or: [Windows: What software do you recommend for editing MP3 ID3 tags?](http://superuser.com/questions/5065/windows-what-software-do-you-recommend-for-editing-mp3-id3-tags/5108#5108)

Answer (score 1):

[MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) Tagger allows to fetch tags & allows you to override them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[OrlSoft Music Manager](http://www.orlsoft.com/osmm.asp) - can encode, transcode, decode most misic formats, manage tags (effectively, verified).

Tools from Tag menu ("Advanced tag update" mostly) *can* do job for you. Even Full Edition is low-cost shareware

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck in the past using [The Godfather](http://download.cnet.com/The-GodFather/3000-2141_4-10232548.html) and I do believe it to support all of the things you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used [Mp3tag](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mp3tag&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://www.mp3tag.de/en/&ei=EqbCTsSuKOSa2AWLuZzBDg&usg=AFQjCNFJshfGf8BqpeABLKbZhBOklD5FMg&sig2=TqqDAHLRDZ6ygnhVaPictQ&cad=rja) in windows, and I just use id3v2 in linux.